# Error in rendering partial view in asp.net mvc ajax

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

In asp.net ajax, the partial view response replaces the html and only the partial view is rendered. 
In the below snippet, when I click the ActionLink "Steps", the partial view is returned and replaces the Details.cshtml.

What I need is this partial view should replace only the "main-content-div" div.

Please help out. Thanks

View: Details.cshtml

```
<div class="main-body">

<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="left-sidebar extended">

            @Ajax.ActionLink("Steps", "Steps", new { id = ViewBag.Id }, new AjaxOptions { AllowCache = false, UpdateTargetId = "main-content-div", InsertionMode=InsertionMode.Replace })
        </td>
        <td class="main-wrapper">

            <div class="main-content" id="main-content-div">
                This is the default stuff which I'll be replacing...
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="right-sidebar"></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Action Method:

```
[HttpGet]
    public PartialViewResult Steps(string id)
    {
        //reading model from db
        return PartialView("~/Views/Author/Exercise/_StepsPartial.cshtml", Model);
    }
```

Partial View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Model>
<div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Probably because you do not have the correct scripts loaded, or they are in the wring order.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js` to your project for this to work.

Go to the Nuget Console Package Manager console and type:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax
```

You then just need to add a reference at the top of your `_Layout.cshtml` or View to the relevant script:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
```